# Can't resolve .scss files in .jsx using import

Tags: node.js, webpack, reactjs, webpack-dev-server

When I try to build my react app, I'm getting an error.

`webpack-dev-server --progress --inline --watch`.

```
ERROR in ./app/index.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'styles/main' in '/Users/jono/dev/recipist/app'
 @ ./app/index.jsx 11:12-34
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./app/index.jsx
```

I am importing in **[index.jsx](https://github.com/jonofan/recipist/blob/master/app/index.jsx)** using `import style from 'styles/main';`

This is what my tree looks like:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── index.jsx
│   └── styles
│       └── main.scss
├── index.html
├── output
│   └── bundle.js
├── package.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

**webpack.config.js**: https://github.com/jonofan/recipist/blob/master/webpack.config.js

I have also tried referencing the full extension without using resolve extensions in the config, but same issue.

Comment: what happens if you do `import style from './styles/main.scss'`

Comment: It is now complaining about resolving css-loader, which seems a step in the right direction. Thanks! @finalfreq I thought the . meant the root of the application. Does it mean the root of my entry point defined in webpack.config.js?

Comment: the ./ means current working directory so in that case would be `app`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With how you have it configured it isn't pointing the right file path.

use `import style from './styles/main.scss'` instead

also makes sure you have installed `css-loader` `sass-loader` and `style-loader` through npm and saved into your package.json

Comment: Correct, I had forgotten to install css-loader. I can now reference my scss using className='person'. Should style={styles.person} also work? (I renamed some things.) It doesn't seem to add the class to the rendered html.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this you should change **css-loader** `modules` option to `true`:

```
test: /\.(scss)$/,
use: [
{
    loader: "style-loader"
},
{
    loader: "css-loader",
    options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        modules: true,
    }
 },
 {
     loader: "sass-loader",
     options: {
         sourceMap: true
     }
}]
```